# Stop being a pu@$y ... divergence from original meaning and current usage?

Tags: expressions, offensive-language, commonweath-english

The Latin word *pusillanimous* was too long, so it was shortened to "pussy" while holding its original meaning "cowardly" [feel free to edit the question and bring a longer etymological story and/or to clarify it in the answers].

However, it seems that when used in the vulgar language, as in the expression

> Stop being a pu@$y

It's always charged not only with gender-based meaning, but with the underlying sexual meaning ... am I correct? Are there different local usages/understandings?

ps: This question has been triggered by the comments related [to this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/185553/74827) to a question on another SE site.

Comment: I am highly sceptical of the claim that "pussy" in this sense derives from "pusillanimous". For one thing, as stated in the comments on the answer you reference, that derivation is not mentioned in the OED (I don't have access to check). For another, that seems a highly unlikely shortening (eg the vowel is wrong, and *pusillanimous* is only used as an adjective, and *pussy* is only commonly used as a noun).

Comment: _Pussy_ is from puss _n._ + -y _suffix_. _Puss_ is (originally) a conventional pet name for a cat; and possibly originated as an imitative sound representing a call to attract a cat. Other senses (of both _puss_ and _pussy_) are a semantic extension to describe a person showing characteristics associated with a cat.

Comment: For the record, *pusillanimis* is Latin; *pusillanimous* is late Middle English.

Comment: What does "It's always charged not only with gender-based meaning, but with the underlying sexual meaning...am I correct?" mean? "Pussy" has an established slang meaning, which [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pussy) gives as "a weak or cowardly man or boy". Calling someone a pussy doesn't mean you're literally saying they resemble female genitalia, if that's what you're asking. Or are you asking if someone hearing the phrase might think of female genitalia? Are you asking if it's sexist or homophobic or do you have some other subtext?

Comment: @psmears thank for your comment. I have no idea about the OED, so if you have access that would be great. Regarding "the vowel is wrong" we have no definitive idea about how the Latin words were pronounced, so it may be one or two vowels of, isnt' it?

Comment: @StuartF I may call you a "little girl" and it would be offensive on a gender level (to be read broadly as "may be used by children"), then if I call you a "pussy" it is offensive on a gender and also because of the reference to a sexualized part of the body (read as "totally wrong to be used by children").
I am asking about sexualizing a part of the body, therefore yes, I am asking if it is of common understanding across the different local English flavours that "pussy" means the female genitalia (of course, in a demeaning way)

Comment: @Gae.S. thanks, feel free to expand into an answer, would the pronunciation be very different between the late middle english pusillanimous and the late middle english pussy?

Comment: @ermanen great comment. Please provide reference and convert it into an answer.

Comment: @EarlGrey: I don't have access I'm afraid (mentioned that above). We don't know how the Latin root word was

Comment: @EarlGrey: As I mentioned in my comment above, I don't have access to the OED I'm afraid :(. We may not know precisely how the Latin word it came from was pronounced, but we _do_ know how the word *pusillanimous* is pronounced in *English*, and (at least in my dialect, standard southern UK English) that would not easily lend itself to being abbreviated to "pussy".

Answer (score 5):

That's the first I've ever heard about 'pusillanimous' having anything to do with the etymology of 'pussy'. I'd be very surprised if there's any truth in it.
'Pusillanimous' entered the language in the 15th century (https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=pusillanimous) and would have been restricted to the educated classes who understood Latin. 'Pussy', on the other hand, appears to have been in the language ever since its Germanic beginnings, because it's related to the Dutch *poes*, Low German *puse* and Norse *puss* (https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=pussy). Being slang, its users are unlikely to have even been aware of the word pusillanimous.

There is definitely a major overlap between the 'cat' meaning of pussy and the more offensive anatomical meaning. In fact it's not clear when the meanings separated, and by how much. So it's possible that being 'a pussy' is conceptually related to being a scaredy-cat... or it could be a more generalised insult involving comparing someone to genitalia.

Answer (score 2):

*Pussy* used to be a common, perfectly innocent way of referring to a domestic cat, and in Victorian times was extended to be a nickname for a little girl. c.f. Rosa, the protagonist's young fiancée in Dickens' *Edwin Drood*, whom he calls 'Pussy' until she decides it is rather childish and patronising.

I think it has only been since the mid-20th century (?) that the vulgar meaning has become so widely known that the word can't be used without raising a snigger .

Comment: Or a cringe....